# Error while loading image on device (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I got this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

when I tried to run my app on a device.

The error come from this line :

```
self.viewFond.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "pierre.png")!)
```

It's working great on the simulator but not in the device. I understand that it can't find the image but I don't understand why.

Comment: Filenames are case-sensitive on real devices. Check the real filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling the complier to use a image but it can't find it. Try removing the `.png` extension and check if that image really exists in your project.

```
self.viewFond.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "pierre")!)
```

Also make sure you are uppercasing the letters in the right way. It could be "Pierre" instead of "pierre". The simulator isn't case-sensitive, a real device is.

Comment: Thank you, I put the image in Images.xcasset and now it's working.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark my answer as correct by selecting the tick image if my answer solved your issue.